# How to make radio buttons and check box read only in open office itext library

Tags: java, itext, openoffice-basic

I have created template form using open office.Im assigning values to them from Java code.I don't want user to modify PDF after creation.Im able to implement it for textbox by using read-only property.But how to achieve same for check box and radio buttons.Thanks!

Comment: Please show your non-working code, also see http://itext.2136553.n4.nabble.com/Unmodifiable-radiobuttons-checkboxes-in-table-cell-td3160916.html

Comment: @NikhilJoshi - Thanks for reply.As read in your referenced document there is no inbuilt property for radio buttons,checkboxes.So I have replaced them with textbox.